# How to show firestore uid etc. on Stripe Dasboard?

Tags: swift, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am trying to create stripe customer id. and trying to show my firestore uid as my Stripe customer id. what I have done so far i) I have created firestore id and linked it to my app. ii) I have created cloud functions i.e createStripeCustomer as index.js on my computer and suucessfully deployed it on the function console as you can see below:-

[image]

I have also create a collection - "stripe_customers" with firestore document uid  “ljO8PXBpI6gyqliXOTeqJf08dQ22” with email  “test@again.com”, see image below:-

[image: firestoreconsole]

Now, I want - when the correct ViewController code should be, so that when I click a button in my app i.e. ViewController, then my  firestore document uid i.e. “ljO8PXBpI6gyqliXOTeqJf08dQ22” should show as the stripe customer id. If that is not possible, the firestore document uid “ljO8PXBpI6gyqliXOTeqJf08dQ22” should be linked with my Stripe Customer id with email  “test@again.com” when I click a button on the  ViewController.

The most important thing that should it should show on Stripe Dashboard .

Now my Viewcontroller code is:-

```
   import UIKit
   import Stripe
   import Firebase

   class NewStripeViewController: UIViewController, STPAuthenticationContext {
  let functions = Functions.functions()
   // MARK: UIViews
  var productStackView=UIStackView()
  var paymentStackView=UIStackView()
  var productImageView=UIImageView()
  var productLabel=UILabel()
  var payButton=UIButton()
  var loadingSpinner=UIActivityIndicatorView()
  var outputTextView=UITextView()
  var paymentTextField=STPPaymentCardTextField()
  let backendURL : String =   "console.firebase.google.com/project/totemic-point-318509/overview"


   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Setup UI (images, labels, debug text view)
    // Also setup STPPaymentCardTextField from Stripe-iOS
    self.setupUI()
    }

    // MARK: UIView setup

    func setupUI() {
    setupProductImage()
    setupProductLabel()
    setupLoadingSpinner()
     setupPaymentTextField()
    setupPayButton()
    setUptOutputTextView()

    self.productStackView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:70,width:330, height:150)
    self.productStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
   self.productStackView.alignment = .center
   self.productStackView.axis = .vertical
   self.productStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
 
 self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productImageView)
   self.productStackView.setCustomSpacing(10,after:self.productImageView)
   self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productLabel)

  self.view.addSubview(self.productStackView)

  self.paymentStackView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:250,width:300,height:100)
   self.paymentStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
  self.paymentStackView.alignment = .fill
  self.paymentStackView.axis = .vertical
  self.paymentStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing


              self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.paymentTextField)
   self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.payButton)

    self.view.addSubview(self.paymentStackView)
   }

  func setupProductImage() {
  self.productImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:50, y:50,     width:275, height:200))

  self.productImageView.image = UIImage(named:"ic_cart")
 self.productImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

  }

   func setupProductLabel() {
   self.productLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:270, width:      self.view.frame.width, height:50)
   self.productLabel.text = "buy a stripe press book for $ 5"
   self.productLabel.textAlignment = . center
     }

  func setUptOutputTextView() {
  self.outputTextView.frame =   CGRect(x:0,y:420,width:self.view.frame.width-50, height:100)
  self.outputTextView.center.x = self.view.center.x
  self.outputTextView.textAlignment = .left
  self.outputTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:20)
  self.outputTextView.text = ""
  self.outputTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
  self.outputTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
  self.outputTextView.isEditable = false
  self.view.addSubview(self.outputTextView)
  }
 
  func setupPaymentTextField() {
  self.paymentTextField.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 300,  height:50)
     }

    func setupPayButton() {
    self.payButton.frame = CGRect(x:60, y:480, width: 150, height:50)
    self.payButton.setTitle("submit payment", for:.normal)
    self.payButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for:.normal)
    self.payButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.payButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red:50/250,green:50/250,blue:90/250,alpha:1.0)
    self.payButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.payButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
      }
    func setupLoadingSpinner() {
    self.loadingSpinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
   self.loadingSpinner.frame = CGRect(x:60, y:400, width: 25,         height:25)
    self.loadingSpinner.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.view.addSubview(self.loadingSpinner)
  }

    func startLoading() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.loadingSpinner.startAnimating()
    self.loadingSpinner.isHidden=false
      }
     }

   func stopLoading() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.loadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
    self.loadingSpinner.isHidden=true
     }
    }

    func displayStatus(_ message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.outputTextView.text! += message + "\n"
         self.outputTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(self.outputText  View.text.count - 1, 1))
     }
   }

    // MARK: Button Actions

      @objc func pay() {
      // 1) [server-side] Create a PaymentIntent
      // 2) [client-side] Confirm the PaymentIntent

    // make a POST request to the /create_payment_intent endpoint
     self.startLoading()
     self.displayStatus("Creating PaymentIntent")

      self.createPaymentIntent { (paymentIntentResponse, error) in
      if let error=error {
        self.stopLoading()
        self.displayStatus(error.localizedDescription)
        print(error)
        return
           }
        else {
        guard let responseDictionary=paymentIntentResponse as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("Incorrect response")
            return
        }

        print(responseDictionary)
        let clientSecret=responseDictionary["secret"] as! String

        self.displayStatus("Created PaymentIntent")

        // Confirm the PaymentIntent using STPPaymentHandler
        // implement delegates for STPAuthenticationContext

         let paymentIntentParams=STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
         let paymentMethodParams=STPPaymentMethodParams(card:            self.paymentTextField.cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
             paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams=paymentMethodParams

        STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams:  paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in

            self.stopLoading()

            var resultString=""

            switch (status) {
            case .canceled:
                resultString="Payment canceled"
            case .failed:
                resultString="Payment failed, please try a different card"
            case .succeeded:
                resultString="Payment successful"
            }

            print(resultString)
            self.displayStatus(resultString)
        }
    }
   }

}

      func createPaymentIntent(completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
     functions.httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call(["amount": 1099]) { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
    // ...
    }
    if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
    // do something with data
     }
            }
   }

    // MARK: STPAuthenticationContext Delegate

     func authenticationPresentingViewController() -> UIViewController {
return self
   }
 }
```

My index.js is -

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');

   const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1');
    // initialize admin SDK with defaults
  admin.initializeApp();




 // [START chargecustomer]
 // Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is written to the firestore
          exports.createStripeCharge = functions.firestore.document('stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const val = snap.data();
  try {
    // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection(`stripe_customers`).doc(context.params.userId).get()
    const snapval = snapshot.data();
    const customer = snapval.customer_id
    // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
    // protecting against double charges
    const amount = val.amount;
    const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
    const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
    if (val.source !== null) {
      charge.source = val.source;
      }
      const response = await stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey});
    // If the result is successful, write it back to the     database
    return snap.ref.set(response, { merge: true });
    } catch(error) {
    // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-   friendly way, while
    // still logging an exception with StackDriver
    console.log(error);
    await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, {  merge: true });
      return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
     }
   });
    
   // [END chargecustomer]]

   // When a user is created, register them with Stripe
   exports.createStripeCustomer =        functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
   const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email:   user.email});
   return         admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({   customer_id: customer.id});
     });

 // Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe         payment source token to Realtime database
  exports.addPaymentSource =         functions.firestore.document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    
   const source = snap.data();
   const token = source.token;
    if (source === null){
    return null;
     }

    try {
const snapshot = await  admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).get();
const customer =  snapshot.data().customer_id;
const response = await stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source: token});
return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).collection("sources").doc(response.fingerprint).set(response, {merge: true});
 } catch (error) {
await snap.ref.set({'error':userFacingMessage(error)}, {merge:true});
return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
   }
 });

 // When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
      exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) =>   {
     const snapshot = await    admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).get()   ;
      const customer = snapshot.data();
      await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
     return      admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).delete(     );
    });

    // To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose error report with Stackdriver rather
    // than simply relying on console.error. This will calculate users affected + send you email
    // alerts, if you've opted into receiving them.
    // [START reporterror]
    function reportError(err, context = {}) {
    // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will  receive the log
     // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but     must contain "err"
    // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error    Reporting.
   const logName = 'errors';
   const log = logging.log(logName);

      // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
            
    const metadata = {
    resource: {
     type: 'cloud_function',
     labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
     },
   };

   // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
    const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
     serviceContext: {
     service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
  resourceType: 'cloud_function',
     },
     context: context,
      };

  // Write the error log entry
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
     if (error) {
     return reject(error);
    }
      return resolve();
      });
      });
      }
     // [END reporterror]

     // Sanitize the error message for the user
     function userFacingMessage(error) {
     return error.type ? error.message : 'An error occurred,      developers have been alerted';
      }
```

Now, everytime I click on "Submit Payment" button, it just says "creating PaymentIntent" as shown in the figure below: -

[image]

and  the Stripe Dashboard is empty:-

[image]

I have tried and failed. I hope you will assist me with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sorts of custom attributes are best used via `metadata` on Stripe objects, including for Customer objects ([api reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-metadata)). I'm not sure how this would be done with your particular integration, but it would be added to whichever code you use to create customers.

It would appear in the Dashboard like this:
[image]

and in search:
[image]

Comment: have you tried hardcoded values to see if stripe api works?